# How do find out what eigenvalue represent a state in a state space vector?

Tags: matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, determinant, optimal-control

Let's say that I have a system matrix **A** and to find out the eigenvalues $\lambda$ ,I do this:

$$ \hbox{det}(\lambda I - A) = 0 $$

Then to find out if the system are controllable, I uses the [Hautus Lemma test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hautus_lemma) . This thest is mutch better that the regular $\hbox{rank}(\hbox{ctrb}(A, B)) = n\ $ test.
Anyway! Here it is:

$$ \hbox{rank}([\lambda_i I - A, B]) = n$$

Let's say that I got 3 eigenvalues of **A**. They are $\lambda_1 = -2$ , $\lambda_2 = -10$ and $\lambda_3 = -0.5$.  Now I test if the system is controllable:
\begin{align} 
\hbox{rank}([\lambda_1 I - A, B]) &= 3\, ,\\
\hbox{rank}([\lambda_2 I - A, B]) &= 1\, ,\\
\hbox{rank}([\lambda_3 I - A, B]) &= 3
\end{align}

So something went wrong here! I got 3 eigenvalues, which mean that my state vector is the length 3. That means that my rank of the system should be number 3. But this:
$$ \hbox{rank}([\lambda_2 I - A, B]) = 1$$
gives number 1 buy using $\lambda_2 = 10$.

**Question:**
Does this mean that something is wrong with my state vector at row number 2 beacuse the eigenvalue $\lambda_2 = 10$ must reprecent the state vector $x_2$ ?

Comment: It sure looks that way, but there’s no way for us to tell since you’ve provided nothing but the eigenvalues you computed.

Comment: Don't you know state space models?

Comment: When you ask what you did wrong, no one but a mind reader will be able to tell you unless you show your work.

Comment: @DanielMårtensson you need to provide the $A$ matrix. Before anything usefull can be said.

Comment: @DanielMårtensson This result only shows that your system is not controllable. According to Hautus, you should have gotten $rank=3$ for ALL eigenvalues iff your system is controllable. Doing Kalman's test should hold the same result ($rank \neq 3$)